# MongoDB- How to $project items from an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, aggregation-framework

**Playground**  https://mongoplayground.net/p/tIMLOtWTnno

**DATA:**

```
[

  {
    "_id": "1",
    "data": {                     // How to remove this "data" Field
      "colour": "Blue",
      "size": "12",
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "data": {                     // How to remove this "data" Field
      "colour": "Silver",
      "size": "20",
    }
  }

]
```

---

**I want to remove the `data` field.**

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "colour": "Blue",
    "size": "12",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "colour": "Silver",
    "size": "20",
    
  }
]
```

**Tried it like this:**

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    data: {
      $objectToArray: "$data"
    }
  },
  
},
{
  $unwind: "$data"
},
{
  $project: {
    "$data.k": "$data.v"
  }
})
```

---

**How to do this ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query1**

- set to add the fields in the root and remove the data

*you could use also project

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71358942-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"colour":"$data.colour",
   "size":"$data.size",
   "data":"$$REMOVE"}}])
```

**Query2**

- more general solution without the need to type each field in project
- merge the data embeded object with the root, and make it new root
- remove the data field

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71358942-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":["$data", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$project":{"data":0}}])
```